# xml to json to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

my xml :

```
...
<phone type="cell" ext=""></phone>
<phone type="work" ext="">(123) 456 7890</phone>
...
```

in php; I json_encode($xml) and echo to browser.
the browser recieves:

```
...
"phone": [
    {
        "@attributes": {
            "type": "cell",
            "ext": ""
        }
    }, "(123) 456 7890", {
        "@attributes": {
            "type": "work",
            "ext": ""
        }
    }
]
```

in javascript

```
...
var phone_rec = {};
phone_rec.addPhone = function(argument, sender) { 
    function newPhone() {
        this.phone = {};
        this.phone.@attributes = {};
        this.phone.@attributes.type = null;
        this.phone.@attributes.ext = null;
    };
    return newPhone();
}...
```

this falls apart and I am unable to reference this.phone for the number .

Comment: You provided tons of unnecessary details which made answering your question harder. PHP and XML to JSON conversion is absolutely irrelevant, what counts when investigating JavaScript errors is what the browser sees. And quoting the actual JavaScript error that you see is a **must**.

Comment: `phone.@attributes` is not valid JavaScript. Should be `phone['@attributes']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you don't call `newPhone` on your object, by default `this` will equal to `window` however. Call it like this instead:

```
return newPhone.call(this);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call for documentation.

In addition, `phone.@attributes` will produce a syntax error as noted correctly by Felix Kling (identifiers cannot contain `@`). You should access this property like this:

```
 this.phone["@attributes"].type = null;
```